# CakePHP shell unit tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to write unit tests for a CakePHP shell that I'm creating, but they aren't mentioned in the [testing documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html) or bake:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
Bake Tests
Path: /home/brad/sites/farmlogs/app/Test/
---------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------
Select an object type:
---------------------------------------------------------------
1. Model
2. Controller
3. Component
4. Behavior
5. Helper
Enter the type of object to bake a test for or (q)uit (1/2/3/4/5/q)
```

Since CakePHP doesn't appear to have a default shell testing setup, what should the structure of my basic shell tests look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging from examples in Mark Story's [AssetCompress](https://github.com/markstory/asset_compress/tree/2.x/Test/Case) and the CakeDC's [Migrations](https://github.com/CakeDC/migrations/tree/master/Test/Case), just mimic the directory structure for other tests:

```
Test/
  Case/
    Console/
      Command/
        Task/
          MyShellTaskTest.php
        MyShellTest.php
```

Your tests can just extend the CakeTestCase object, just like any other generic test:

```
class MyShellTest extends CakeTestCase {
}
```

If needed, you can override the base shell, just like you would do with a Controller test:

```
class TestMyShell extends MyShell {
}
```

Nothing all that special, just stick with the conventions.

Answer (score 1):

I think app/lib/lib/Cake/Console/Command/TestShellTest.php can be a reference.

1、create file in app/Test/Case/Console/Command/yourfile.php,  state your classes using `App::uses('your class', 'relative path').`
for example:

```
App::uses('yourShellClass', 'Console/Command');
App::uses('ShellDispatcher', 'Console');
App::uses('Shell', 'Console');
```

2、write a mock class B from your shell class A, whose function use data returns in class A.
for example:

```
 class TestYourShellClass extends YourShellClass {
         public function F1 ($parms){
               //if you need use database here, you can 
               //$this->yourModel = ClassRegistry::init('yourModel');
               return $this->_F1($parms);      
         }

    }
```

3、write test class of class A, you need to init it in startup.
for example:

```
 class YourShellClassTest extends CakeTestCase {
        public function setUp()
        {
            parent::setUp();
            $out = $this->getMock('ConsoleOutput', [], [], '', false);
            $in = $this->getMock('ConsoleInput', [], [], '', false);
            $this->Shell = $this->getMock(
                // this is your class B, which mocks class A.
                'TestYourShellClass',
                ['in', 'out', 'hr', 'help', 'error', 'err', '_stop', 'initialize', '_run', 'clear'],
                [$out, $out, $in]
            );
            $this->Shell->OptionParser = $this->getMock('ConsoleOptionParser', [], [null, false]);
        }

        /**
         *  tear down method.
         *  
         *  @return void
         */
        public function tearDown()
        {
            parent::tearDown();
            unset($this->Dispatch, $this->Shell);
        }       
   }
```

4、 the test function can be like this.

```
 /**
 *  test _F1.
 *  
 *  @return void
 */
public function testF1()
{
    $this->Shell->startup();
    $return = $this->Shell->F1();
    $expectedSellerCount = 14;
    $this->assertSame($expectedSellerCount, $return);
}
```

and then you can view result in http://yourdomain/test.php